# Centos installation failled

Tags: linux

I am new to the Linux and trying to set up my server on Virtual Box but once finished create a virtual machine and start to install CentOS 7 for 64-bit on my windows 7 with a 32-bit, I get this error shown here:

[image]

I have tried to do the research of how this issue can be addressed and the only solution was to change my setting of virtualization technologies in BIOS. Unfortunately I ended up with no solution.

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Welcome to U&L SE. What error do you get? Please [edit] your question to provide the promised screenshot.

Comment: thanks @roaima,it is a link not a screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot run a 64-bit OS guest on a 32-bit host.

You can run 32-bit guest on a 64-bit host, but this won't help you because you're running 32-bit Windows. So the only remaining solution is to run a 32-bit guest on a 32-bit host. You'll need the [32-bit installation for CentOS 6](http://isoredirect.centos.org/centos/6/isos/i386/) rather than the 64-bit one for CentOS 7.

Comment: thanks so much @roaima,your help is much appreciated,i can see how you have edited my post and formulate it well.like that,let me try that way,i will give feedback